# How to set up nginx upstream with php on ubuntu?

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, fpm

On ubuntu 18.04, I have nginx running

```
upstream vault {
  server 127.0.0.1:8001;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name vault.shopshop.space;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass vault;
    }
}
```

The idea is that when I hit vault.shopshop.space, it should hit a simple php backgroud serivce listening 8001

This php background service is from here: https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/tutorial/first-app.html

```
<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require '../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\App;
$app->get('/hello/{name}', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
    $name = $args['name'];
    $response->getBody()->write("Hello, $name");

    return $response;
});
$app->run();
```

I run this `php -S localhost:8001`, I can curl in my ubuntu server.

```
curl http://localhost:8001/hi/bla
```

will output `hello, bla`

run `netstat -npl`

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      13004/nginx: master 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      539/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      643/sshd            
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12961/php-fpm: mast 
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      643/sshd            
tcp6       0      0 ::1:8001                :::*                    LISTEN      12325/php           
udp    49920      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           539/systemd-resolve 
udp        0      0 45.76.119.188:68        0.0.0.0:*                           512/systemd-network 
raw6       0      0 :::58                   :::*                    7           512/systemd-network
```

the simple php service is listening 8001 in ip4 and ip6

ufw firewall

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Nginx Full                 ALLOW       Anywhere                  
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8001                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Nginx Full (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
8001 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

firewall can listen 8001

www.conf, only listen 8001

```
/etc/php/5.6/fpm/pool.d/www.conf

;listen = /run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock
listen = 8001
```

**The problem:**

```
http://vault.shopshop.space/hi/bla, 404

http://vault.shopshop.space, default nginx page
```

I expect hello bla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is configuration example for nginx + php-fpm in [documentation](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/start/web-servers.html).

You haven't in your configuration:

- root
- fastcgi params
- etc

Here is example with upstream:

```
upstream vault {
    server 127.0.0.1:8001;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name vault.shopshop.space;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/vault.shopshop.space_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/vault.shopshop.space_access.log;

    root /path/to/public;
    index index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
     }

    location ~ \.php {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_pass vault;
    }
}
```

You should fix path to public dir in root string.

Comment: awesome. That is great.

Answer (score 0):

Everything that @mindfl said, plus you have no catch all location block. Your only location block is this, which defines a regex match for requests ending with `.php`

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass vault;
}
```

`http://vault.shopshop.space/hi/bla` doesn't end with `.php`, and as you have no `index` or `try_files` directives then that request is never going to be processed by that location block.

The config posted by @mindfl should be a good starting point for you.